# How to exclude field in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm taking information from a table:

```
<xsl:template match="table1">
  <xsl:element name="ApplicantAddress">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And I want to make sure I don't include a field from that table.  Is that possible?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a *complete* and short solution that is completely based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern: the using and overriding of the identity rule. Explanation and link are also provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push style:

```
<xsl:template match="table1">
   <ApplicantAddress>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::unwanted-element)]"/>
   </ApplicantAddress>
</xsl:template>
```

Pull style:

```
<xsl:template match="table1">
   <ApplicantAddress>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </ApplicantAddress>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table1/unwanted-element"/>
```

Comment: So: `<xsl:template match="table1"><ApplicantAddress><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></ApplicantAddress></xsl:template>      <xsl:template match="table1/field1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="table1">
  <ApplicantAddress>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </ApplicantAddress>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (which you missed to provide):

```
<table1>
 <a/>
 <b/>
 <c/>
 <d/>
</table1>
```

**produces the wanted result** (element `b` not copied):

```
<ApplicantAddress>
  <a />
  <b />
  <d />
</ApplicantAddress>
```

**Explanation**: Using and overriding the [**identity rule**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)/template is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern. Here we override the identity rule with a empty-body-template matching `c` and this ensures this element is ignored ("deleted"/not-copied).

Comment: I think you mean element `c` right?  Is this any different than the other answer, or is this tomato tomato stuff?  :)  Thanks.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity: Yes, I meant `c` and I'll edit my answer. My answer is different than the other one because it provides the identity rule (and the complete stylesheet to use). @Alejandro's answer assumes that the identity rule is somewhere in the stylesheet. He doesn't even mention this assumption and just wrapping his code in an `<xsl:stylesheet>` element doesn't copy any child elements of the `table1` element -- just try and verify this.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I didn't put everything in the answer just to make sure I didn't accidentally put any proprietary information.  In the current XSLT file I'm editing (new to XSLT files) I do not have the strip-space, but I have `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />`.  Will I need the strip-space and have to change my output?  I also do have the first template declaration you put.

Comment: @Dimitre: It's not entirely correct to say @Alejandro's answer assumes the identity rule's presence, it's not needed in this case; the OP's own template already processes all child nodes of the `table1` element. Adding the identity rule may actually cause other parts of the XML to be included unintentionally.

Comment: Another question.  I have that same field in multiple tables and would like to remove them in one swoop.  My collegue said doing <xsl:template match="field1" /> will do that for all tables.  Is that correct?

Comment: @XstreamINsanity: Yes, if there are other contexts in which the `field1` element should be preserved (there are none in the XML document you provided!), then you need to specify more unambiguously the context for deletion, for example: `<xsl:template match="table1/field1"/>`.

Comment: @Flynn1179: No, the OP's vode has only: `    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> ` -- this will only copy the string values of any atributes and the string values of all descendent text nodes. Therefore, I am right that @Alejandro's transformation just wrapped in an `<xsl:stylesheet>` doesn't copy the children elements of `table1`. Why should we argue at all? Everybody can check this themselves.

Comment: @Dimitre: I was making the more general point that the identity template, while incredibly useful, isn't always appropriate, and shouldn't automatically be assumed to be required; there's nothing about the OP's sample that indicates any node should be copied as is, it's entirely possible (and quite common) that the output has no resemblance to the input, such as transforming an xml document to html. It's very possible that the other child nodes of `table` need to be processed by other templates rather than copied with the identity rule.

Comment: @flynn1179: The op says: "I want to make sure I don't include a field from that table." This means that except for this specific field, the other fields will not be skipped.